# Application that can convert multiview to oblique projection, vice versa

Tags: drawing

I am looking for a webapps or if possible an application that can convert `multiview` to `oblique`

Example: (Left side is [`multiview`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_orthographic_projection) right side is [`oblique`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection))

[image]

It does not need to be 100% accurate, something like 50% will do and will serve as my guidance when doing exercises.

**Edit:**

I'm looking for a software in any Windows OS preferably, if not possible you can suggest any OS.